# Adding new column and define the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
SELECT *
 from  gp.db
 WHERE client ='paper'
 and packaging in ('Test1','Test2')
 and run_date  between  "07/01/21" and "07/03/2021"
```

This is the result:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

1. A new column: "Owners"
2. Define such that anything test1 and test2 from "packaging column" is for Manager1 and Manager2 respectively on "Owners" column

the end result:

[image]

Comment: where does the value for `Owners` comes from ?

Comment: A simple case expression would suffice. What have you tried?

Comment: @Squirrel I defined the value. The idea is to know how many test1 packaging is own by Manager 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ff.packaging,ff.run_date,
 CASE
 WHEN ff.packaging='test1' then 'manager 1'
 when ff.packaging='test2' then 'manager 2'
 else 'manager 0'
  end as manager
 from  gp.db ff
 WHERE ff.client ='paper'
 and ff.packaging in ('Test1','Test2')
  and ff.run_date  between  "07/01/21" and "07/03/2021"
```

Comment: how can we join the tables. The difference with the 2nd SQL is , it only looks at priority 1

Comment: SELECT ff.packaging,ff.run_date,ff.priority
 CASE
 WHEN ff.packaging='test3' then 'manager 3'
 else 'manager 0'
  end as manager
 from  gp.db ff
 WHERE ff.client ='paper'
 and ff.packaging in ('Test3')
 and ff.priority = 1
  and ff.run_date  between  "07/01/21" and "07/03/2021"

Comment: ELECT ff.packaging,ff.run_date,ff.priority
 CASE
 WHEN ff.packaging='test1' then 'manager 1'
 when ff.packaging='test2' then 'manager 2'
 else 'manager 0'
  end as manager
 from  gp.db ff
 WHERE ff.client ='paper'
 and ff.packaging in ('Test1','Test2')
 and ff.priority in (1,2)
  and ff.run_date  between  "07/01/21" and "07/03/2021"